# How to fix error "SessionNotCreatedException" with edge webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

When I run this:

`driver = selenium.webdriver.Edge(executable_path="msedgedriver.exe")`

I got the error `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found`

When I had a look for possible solutions I only found information on the firefox browser not microsoft edge.

Not sure why the session does not start.

Comment: Any solutions?...

Comment: Turned out I was using the wrong edge Web driver exe.